# mobile app usability - UX design

Tags: gui-design, ux-field, ux-designer

what to do in this case, users feel the text is overwhelming and not organized, should I put the fields under each other? but all other sections are in the design of this field, If I did so would that break the consistency or what?
Thanks
[image]

[image]